# How can I comment on a table - MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have been trying to comment on a table I have created with  `comment = 'this is a comment'`

But it always results in an error. I have tried placing it in the following ways:

```
create table info comment = 'this is a comment about table info' (
...
);
```

```
create table info (
places varchar(15) not null,
solar_system varchar(20),
primary key (places),
comment = 'this is a comment about table info'
);
```

```
create table info (
places varchar(15) not null,
solar_system varchar(20),
comment = 'this is a comment about table info',
primary key (places)
);
```

```
create table info (comment = 'this is a comment about table info',
places varchar(15) not null,
solar_system varchar(20),
primary key (places)
);
```

What should I do for the comment on the table to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can comment [columns and tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/#table-options)

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  example_column INT COMMENT "This is an example column",
  another_column2 VARCHAR(100) COMMENT "One more column"
) COMMENT="This is a comment about table";
```

so in your case

```
create table info (
    places varchar(15) not null,
    solar_system varchar(20),
    primary key (places)
) comment = 'this is a comment about table info';
```

Comment: `COMMENT` is a [Table option](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/#table-options) so it goes after the final `)` of the table definition.

Comment: thx @danblack i added the link